# JavaScript change time format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change time format from
'2021-03-04 14:47:50'
to
'2021-03-04T14:47:50Z'.

How can make it work? Do I need to convert it to a Date object? Thank you

Update:
I just figured out I can use **time.replace(/\s/g, 'T') + 'Z'** to put characters to the string. Thank you again for anyone who answers my question

Comment: can you please explain this question in better way, it's hard clear about your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a `Date` object, after that call `toISOString` method

```
const date = new Date('2021-03-04 14:47:50');
console.log(date.toISOString()); // return 2021-03-04T11:47:50.000Z
```

UPD: with timezone offset

```
var isoDateTime = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString(); // 2021-03-04T14:47:50.000Z
```

Comment: This would only be valid in case your local time is UTC+0 thus why the outcome shows 11:47:50 instead of 14:47:50 in your example.